# import very large XML file (60GB) into MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml, import

I have a XML file with a size of almost 60 GB that I would like to import into a MySQL database. I have root access to my server, but I don't know how to handle files of this size.

You guys have any idea?

Normally I use Navicat, but it gave up...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a little out of my area of knowledge but would this work ?

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/pathtofile/file.xml' 
INTO TABLE my_tablename(name, date, etc);
```

I know this sort of thing work with <1GB files, but I've yet to work with large files.

Hope this helps !

**EDIT** 
If that doesn't work for you go take a look at the LOAD DATA documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a try :-)

Comment: Not a problem, let me know how you go with it.

Comment: I've been running a `LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE` for what feels like an hour or two on a 3gb XML file. Sure is slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a command line xml splitter to split it into manageable size files first. Google to find one.